# Disbale editing row in sharepoint based on column

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, permissions, approval-process

Is there any way to disable a row in a SharePoint list based on a column value?

I have a time off list that I would like to disable once it has been approved.

So if approval status is approved you can view the row but should not be able to edit or delete.

You can add a new row if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SharePoint 2010 platform workflow to remove item level permission or replace item level permission with Impersonation Step.

[image]

Set start workflow automatically when an item is created.

Reference:

http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-give-item-level-permission-through-sharepoint-workflow/